# How do I program "else if" from loading wrong figures in a .html calculator

Tags: javascript

```
if (Cost_Battery <=0) {Battery_kWh_Day =0}
else if (Cost_Battery <=2535.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 2.40}
else if (Cost_Battery <=3015.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 3.60}
else if (Cost_Battery <=3775.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 4.80}
else if (Cost_Battery <=4175.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 6.00}
else if (Cost_Battery <=4645.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 7.20}
else if (Cost_Battery <=6720.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 12.00}
else if (Cost_Battery <=7590.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 14.40}

else if (Cost_Battery <=4900.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 4.80} //Results return 12 when it should return 4.8
else if (Cost_Battery <=5875.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 7.20} //Results return 12 when it should return 7.2
else if (Cost_Battery <=7395.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 9.60} //Results return 14.4 when it should return 9.6
else if (Cost_Battery <=8200.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 12.00}
```

// this is only a short version above.
// I have tried to use =4900.00 <=4901.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 4.80} to get the correct result, But that does not work.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do or what is going wrong. All i can say is long chains of `if` or `else if` are imho bad style.

Comment: execution order matters `if (Cost_Battery <=6720.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 12.00}` 4900 < 6720

Comment: Use a lookup table to get rid of all this pointless duplication. At the absolute least **use a `function`**.

Comment: You should also pick one of `mixedCase` or `underscore_style` and not mix the two together into some form that doesn't know which it is.

Comment: I used, else if (Cost_Battery =4900<6720) {Battery_kWh_Day = 4.80}
But the result still gave 12.00

Comment: What I am trying to do, is get Two results, one is the cost and the other is the kWh a Battery supply's.
These figures go into Two separate fields, so they need to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your if elses are badly organized(wrong sequence). Note that this works top to bottom. So when it comes to 4900, it is greater than 4645, but less than 6720. So it returns 12 and stops the looping there. You should organize conditions in correct sequence.

```
if (Cost_Battery <=0) {Battery_kWh_Day =0}
else if (Cost_Battery <=2535.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 2.40}
else if (Cost_Battery <=3015.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 3.60}
else if (Cost_Battery <=3775.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 4.80}
else if (Cost_Battery <=4175.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 6.00}
else if (Cost_Battery <=4645.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 7.20}
else if (Cost_Battery <=4900.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 4.80} 
else if (Cost_Battery <=5875.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 7.20}
else if (Cost_Battery <=6720.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 12.00}
else if (Cost_Battery <=7395.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 9.60}
else if (Cost_Battery <=7590.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 14.40}
else if (Cost_Battery <=8200.00) {Battery_kWh_Day = 12.00}
```

Comment: Thanks KKK,
Yes I do understand that, it is because each set of batteries are selected in a set that are different in quantity, size & capacity.
The drop down list allows for the selection of several different selections, so they need to remain in Groups.
A little like:
 10x 1.2v
 20x 1.2v
 40x 1.2v etc.

So, the prices vary causing the issue.

Comment: This is the test page.
http://www.revetec.com.au/Calculators/Test_Calculator.html

Comment: If there is another method of Java instructions I should be using, I would be interested in knowing.
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter what order your list in HTML. But it should be in proper order in javascript.

Comment: KKK, Thanks mate, you are a legend ! 

It is always the simple thinks that beat me.